# Basic Bootstrap Typeahead functions aren't working for me

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to make a very simple example of bootstrap typeahead, but I can't even seem to do that correctly.  When I type characters into the textbox, it doesn't display any of the possible items.  Can someone explain why?  Is the problem with my external resources?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.9.3/typeahead.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div style="margin: 50px 50px">
        <label for="product_search">Product Search: </label>
        <input id="product_search" type="text" data-provide="typeahead"
            data-source='["Product A", "Product B", "Product C"]'>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/5m44yfyf/